# groovy code not working when object is passed with new keyword

Tags: groovy, hashmap

Why this code is not working?

```
println getValueFromMap(new HashMap().put("a","aaaaa"))
//Its calling Method
def String getValueFromMap(Map<String,String> mapObject){
    return mapObject.get("a")
}
```

whereas following code is working.

```
Map<String,String> fooMap=new HashMap()
fooMap.put("b","bbbbb")
println getValueFromMap(fooMap)
//Its calling Method
def String getValueFromMap(Map<String,String> mapObject){
    return mapObject.get("b")
}
```

Please explain.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are using Java-style syntax for the maps instead of Groovy's Map-literal syntax? Example: `[a:"aaaaa"]` to create a map with one key (`"a"`) and associated value `"aaaaa"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`new HashMap().put("a","aaaaa")`

does not return a `HashMap`, it returns `null`. The `put` method does not return the `HashMap`.

```
Map<String,String> fooMap=new HashMap()
fooMap.put("b","bbbbb")
println getValueFromMap(fooMap)
```

works because you are passing the actual `HashMap` to the method, not the result of the `put` method, which is `null`.